# cannot return the exact values in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm sorry.. I just want to clarify my post earlier.

```
<?php

        $db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=user password=password");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = 8320 AND password = 'admin' ";
        $query = pg_query($sql);
        $row = pg_fetch_array($query);
        var_dump($row); //DUMPS EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED.. BUT WHEN I put it on a function like this.

?>


<?php
        function checkLogin($user_id, $password)
        {
        $db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=user password=password");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id AND password = $password ";
        $query = pg_query($sql);
        $row = pg_fetch_array($query);
        return $row;
        }
?>


//CALL HERE
```

$data = checkLogin(8320, 'admin');
var_dump($data); // dumps NULL

why is it so?

Comment: My answer should fix your problems :) Let me know if it didn't work....

Comment: Is it me, or are you missing a `}`?

Comment: sorry about that.. I changed it already and added the missing quote as well.. I tried calling the function using $data = checkLogin('8320', 'admin'); still NULL is the output.

Comment: So does your first example up there return anything?? The one outside of the function with hardcoded parameters I mean

Comment: You still dont have single quotes around your password though, like in my example ?  password = '$password'

Comment: You can edit your posts. You don't have to post new questions to clarify, just edit the original. Don't edit if it'd totally change the meaning of the original and there are already answers though - that's when a new post would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Password value you are passing `$upassword` and using `$password` also that **string should be enclosed with quotes** like below,

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id AND password = '$password'"
```

Comment: sorry I made some changes.. I tried using your example but still I get a NULL value

Comment: Did you give the $password variable correctly as in param - $upassword

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here...

```
function checkLogin($user_id, $upassword)  //passing $upassword not $password
```

You pass in `$upassword`  but then dont use it, instead you use..just `$password`

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id AND password = '$password'";
```

Change to...

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id AND password = '$upassword'";
```

Simple overlooked syntax error  :)

Comment: Wouldn't that have caused the `var_dump($row);` to spit out `bool(false)` or the like, though...?

Comment: Well either way, if the problem is elsewhere...this is still one of the major errors in his code :)

Comment: I tried: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id AND password = '$password' "; call: $data = checkLogin(8320, "admin"); STILL I GET VALUE NULL

Comment: @user2429302: And what does the error message say?  You *do* have error_reporting set to show notices and warnings, right?

Comment: Yeah but its gotta be $upassword not $password........your function has $upassword as a parameter

Comment: @KyleK: Not any more, it doesn't.

Comment: what happens if you hard code it into the function like the example above.....still call the function....but hardcode....do you get anything like that?

Comment: @user2429302: PHP's database functions don't return null if everything was successful.  (Hell, they don't even return nulls on error.  It's pretty much always `false`.  But that can look like null sometimes, if you're printing it.)  Add a line at the top of your script that says `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);` and see what PHP tells you is wrong.

Comment: For future reference, you generally want to have `display_errors` on and `error_reporting` cranked up on your dev site.  Many people recommend having them off in production, but while you're developing, the error messages can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id AND password = $password ";

should be

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id AND password = '$password' ";
```

Answer (score -1):

Following up on Vinoth's answer, if $user_id is going to be a string that needs to be enclosed in quotes as well. And be careful about sanitizing your user submitted inputs.

Comment: As you are following up on Vinoth's answer, you should add it as a comment to his answer.

Comment: I would have but dont have the rep to comment on other's answers yet.

Comment: Posting a comment as an answer is not an appropriate way around the rep requirement.